# How to hide select options when there is no data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm building a drop-down list with options containing data from a database and want to hide options which have zero data.

I have tried an if statement using continue but failing to catch the live data values from the database.

```
      <select name='Database' title="Choose from database">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <?php foreach($database as $row):
          if ($row['topic'] == 0) {
            continue;
          }
          else {
          ?>
            <option value="<?= $row['topic']; ?>"
            <?php if ($row['topic'] == $_SESSION['prosess']){echo " 
            selected";}?>>
            <?= $row['topic']; ?>
          <?php }?>
          </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
```

Is there any clever javascript-, php-, etc. code that can deactivate/hide options from a database which are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css:

select option:empty {
    display:none
}

Comment: There is going to be one `option` there always i.e the `all` one. So I think your solution might not work.

Comment: It will not check the value of the option. it always check content of the option so it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this.

```
<select name='Database' title="Choose from database">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <?php 
        if(count($database) > 0)
        {
            foreach($database as $row)
            {
    ?>
                <option value="<?= $row['topic']; ?>"
                <?php if ($row['topic'] == $_SESSION['prosess']){echo " 
                selected";}?>>
                <?= $row['topic']; ?>
                <?php }?>
                </option>
    <?php
            }
        } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Hope it helpful for you.